# Get response WSDL in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, wsdl, soap-client

I'm trying to connect to a service which has a single method, which is called "ESBRedeemBasket" I'm instantiating the client ESBRedeemBasket_ESBRedeemBasketHttpService to access this method. This method is composed of "ESBRedeemBasketRequest" which in turn is divided into two "HeaderIn" and "DataInRedeemBasket" the latter is decomposed into "RequestMaster"

The following code is the client "WSLD" which amount within the project as a web reference.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Collections;
using Client.servicioPoints;


namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                ESBRedeemBasket_ESBRedeemBasketHttpService client = new ESBRedeemBasket_ESBRedeemBasketHttpService();
                DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7);
                string s2 = dt.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss");

                var response = client.ESBRedeemBasket(new ESBRedeemBasket()
                {
                    ESBRedeemBasketRequest = new ESBRedeemBasketRequest()
                    {
                        HeaderIn = new HeaderIn()
                        {
                            Username = "Contoso",
                            Company = "Contoso",
                            AppName = "RedeemBasket",
                            IdClient = "Contoso",
                            ReqDate = Convert.ToDateTime(s2)

                        },
                        DataInRedeemBasket = new DataInRedeemBasket()
                        {
                            RequestMaster = new requestMaster()
                            {
                                authType = "CAR",
                                authValue = "U",
                                cardNumber = "848484848429",
                                storeId = "C900",
                                supplierId = "Centos",
                                tillNumber = "J781017939393934541",
                                transactionDate = "0605014",
                                transactionTime = "163000",
                            }
                        },

                    }
                });



                Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
                Console.Write("");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
            // Most specific: 
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} First exception caught.", e);
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
            // Least specific: 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Second exception caught.", e);

                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }



        }
    }
}
```

but always falls on the try and catch...

These are the functions that are within my web reference after the importation of the WSLD:

```
public partial class ESBRedeemBasket {

     private ESBRedeemBasketRequest eSBRedeemBasketRequestField;

     public ESBRedeemBasketRequest ESBRedeemBasketRequest {
            get {
                return this.eSBRedeemBasketRequestField;
            }
            set {
                this.eSBRedeemBasketRequestField = value;
            }
     }
 }


public partial class ESBRedeemBasketRequest {

    private HeaderIn headerInField;

    private DataInRedeemBasket dataInRedeemBasketField;

    public HeaderIn HeaderIn {
         get {
              return this.headerInField;
         }
         set {
             this.headerInField = value;
         }
    }


    public DataInRedeemBasket DataInRedeemBasket {
        get {
            return this.dataInRedeemBasketField;
        }
        set {
           this.dataInRedeemBasketField = value;
        }
    }
}



public partial class HeaderIn {
    private string usernameField;
    private string companyField;
    private string appNameField;
    private string idClientField;
    private System.DateTime reqDateField;
    private bool reqDateFieldSpecified;
    ....

public partial class DataInRedeemBasket {

    private requestMaster requestMasterField;
    private basketReward[] basketRewardField;
    private string transactionIdField;
    ...
```

the next code is the WSLD scheme:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <wsdl:definitions name="ESBRedeemBasket_ESBRedeemBasketHttp_Service" targetNamespace="http://MedTwist/ESBRedeemBasket/Binding" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:Port_0="http://MedTwist/ESBRedeemBasket" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:this="http://MedTwist/ESBRedeemBasket/Binding">
  <wsdl:import namespace="http://MedTwist/ESBRedeemBasket" location="/mockESBRedeemBasket_ESBRedeemBasketHttpBinding?WSDL&interface=ESBRedeemBasket_ESBRedeemBasketHttpBinding&part=ESBRedeemBasket.wsdl" /> 
- <wsdl:binding name="ESBRedeemBasket_ESBRedeemBasketHttpBinding" type="Port_0:ESBRedeemBasket">
  <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
- <wsdl:operation name="ESBRedeemBasket">
  <soap:operation soapAction="" /> 
- <wsdl:input name="ESBRedeemBasketRequest">
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output name="ESBRedeemBasketResponse">
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
- <wsdl:service name="ESBRedeemBasket_ESBRedeemBasketHttpService">
- <wsdl:port name="ESBRedeemBasket_ESBRedeemBasketHttpPort" binding="this:ESBRedeemBasket_ESBRedeemBasketHttpBinding">
  <soap:address location="http://192.168.10.95:8088/mockESBRedeemBasket_ESBRedeemBasketHttpBinding" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

and this is the console error.

[image]

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: <soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode><faultstring>javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException: WSWS3122E: Error: Could not find service sca/ESBRedeemBasket/wsdl/MedTwistContoso_ESBRedeemBasket referenced in URI /MedTwistContosoWeb/sca/ESBRedeemBasket/wsdl/MedTwistContoso_ESBRedeemBasket</faultstring></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body>

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to debug from your snapshot and information.

But try this:

1. Download and install fiddler - http://www.telerik.com/fiddler
2. Then run fiddler (try not to use any other programs using internet)
3. Now run your code until exception.
4. Now go back to fiddler and check the soap request being sent out and being received.
5. This should give you some idea on what request is sent and you can send the request/response to the webservice team to get some help

Comment: you should look at your request/response in the xml view in fiddler